# How to give a warning when format specifiers are passed wrongly to a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, nslog

Suppose i have a method that returns `BOOL` like :

```
+(BOOL) isNewCar {
    //returns YES or NO
}
```

and then I use this method in `NSLog` as :

```
NSLog("Is my car new, the answer is %@", [MyUtil isNewCar]);
```

Then i get compiler warning as :

[image]

If i ignore the warning and  run, the app **crashes**.
Now I have another method called `printCar` which accepts variable arguments just like `NSLog` whose implementation is :

```
 -(void) printCar:(NSString *)msg, ... {
     NSString * contents;
     va_list args;
     va_start(args, msg);
     contents = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:msg arguments:args];
     va_end(args);
     [self writeToFile:contents];
}
```

When i use the above method as :

```
[self printCar:@"The car is mine or not : %@", [MyUtil isNewCar]];
```

the compiler **doesn't** generate a warning. Also, the app crashes.

**Question** : Is there a way to generate a warning if wrong format specifiers are given to our custom method just as `NSLog` does??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , you need `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION` macro to do that , if you press Command and then click on `NSLog` method , you can also see it

```
void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2)
```

so your method

```
-(void) printCar:(NSString *)msg, ...
```

becomes

```
-(void) printCar:(NSString *)msg, ... NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2)
```

you can also Command Click `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION` to see more details about it

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!